# More accurate terms for one-sided business information?

Tags: business-language

The expressions such as *"one-sided"*, *"misleading"*, *"just marketing"* and *"flawed"* are more neutral and casual to more extreme terms such as *"propaganda"*, *"brainwash"* and *"wrong"*. I want to learn very selective terms to describe official material such as annual letters, reports and news carrying very little value in finance and business where information can be hard to understand without being an insider or experienced professional, potentially written in a language that a minority can only understand.

**Helpers**

> 1. What are more lively terms for one-sided information?
> 2. What are more neutral terms for one-sided ambiguous information?
> 3. What are more stressing terms for one-sided clearly wrong information?
> 4. What are more neutrals terms for clear brainwashing?

Comment: I'll note that, while I can come up with many meanings for "one-sided", none of them would come remotely close to "biased". *"You keep using that word. I don't think it means what you think it means."*

Comment: I find the circulating down-votes over my posts highly suspicious. Why such patronizing comment? Have you heard the word inequality or uneven? One-sided action per se is an inequal treatment of something in the same way as biased action. Apparently, one of my other posts made you prejudiced against this post. Do you have a belief that every of my posts require down-votes due to being hhh or for some other characteristic? Are you hesitant to critically review themes in one of your favorite show? I cannot see a reason for down-vote here. At least, say why you are down-voting.

Comment: premisizes? The English in your post is terrrrrible. Full of mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are sort of asking a lot, here. In the future it may be better to try keeping a question to one question. But anyway:

(Do note that a few of the words can drift from category to category)

> What are more lively terms for one-sided information?

- biased
- skewed
- distorted
- tainted
- prejudiced
- discriminatory

> What are more neutral terms for one-sided ambiguous information?

- suspect
- questionable
- tilted
- limited
- not researched
- lazy
- misleading

> What are more stressing terms for one-sided clearly wrong information?

- deceptive
- underhanded
- counterfeit
- unscrupulous
- duplicitous
- fabricated
- falsified
- bullshit

> What are more neutrals terms for clear brainwashing?

- inculcated
- trojan
- viral
- implanted
- possessed
- indoctrinated
- conditioned
- zealous

Applying a thesaurus to any of these could easily extend the list.

Comment: Flawless observations, MrHen.